# The number of $3$-CNF formulas in $n$-variables and the fraction of satisfiable ones

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, lo.logic, computational-complexity

What is the number of $3$-CNF (conjunctive normal form) formulas with $n$ sentential variables and what is the fraction of satisfiable ones? I consider two formulas the same if they are syntactically the same modulo repeated clauses. Thus $$(x_1\lor x_1\lor \lnot x_1)\text{ and } (x_1\lor x_1\lor \lnot x_1)\land (x_1\lor x_1\lor \lnot x_1)$$ are the same while $$(x_1\lor x_1\lor \lnot x_1)\text{ and } (x_1\lor x_1\lor \lnot x_1)\land (x_1\lor \lnot x_1\lor x_1)$$ are **not**. Now, what is the number of these equivalence classes of formulas in $n$ variables and what is the fraction of satisfiable ones? If the exact numbers cannot be given, just some recurrence formulas will do. Does the $\lim$ of the fraction of satisfiable ones go to $0$ as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Marginally related: in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0808.0739.pdf, we showed that the set of satisfiable formula in $\ell$-CNF in $n$ variables is homotopy equivalent to the Alexander dual of the hypergraph of $\ell$-faces of the $n$-cube.

Comment: Name of @JimConant's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428860/the-number-of-3-cnf-formulas-in-n-variables-and-the-fraction-of-satisfiable#comment1103167_428860):  [Conant and Thistlethwaite - Boolean formulae, hypergraphs and combinatorial topology](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0739).

Comment: Your equivalence seems very mild. For example, same collection of clauses in different order = different formula? In a clause, same literals in different order = different clause? So in essence, from all $(2n)^3$ possible clauses, take any subset of any size in any order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the fraction of satisfiable 3-CNF formulas in $n$ variables, it is widely believed that there is a phase transition that occurs depending on how many clauses there are compared to the number of variables.  To be precise, it is conjectured (but not yet proven) that if there are more than $\alpha n$ clauses, then the formula is almost surely unsatisfiable, and if there are less than $\alpha n$ clauses then the formula is almost surely satisfiable (where $\alpha$ is around 4.2667).  This phase transition has been established for $k$-SAT when $k$ is large.  See [Proof of the satisfiability conjecture for large $k$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0650) by Ding, Sly, and Sun.

Comment: Must the clauses in $\alpha n$ do be distinct, in what sense, in the one from my OQ ?

Comment: Also, could you explain to me what means "formula is almost surely satisfiable" in this context ?

Comment: @user1642683 It means that for any fixed $\beta<\alpha$, the limit of the fraction of satisfiable formulas among random $3$-CNF with $n$ variables and $\le\beta n$ clauses as $n\to\infty$ is $1$.

Comment: I should have written $\beta n$ rather than $\le\beta n$ (but this proably does not make a difference).